# WNetAddConnection2 similar method on UNIX

Tags: c++, windows, unix

Is there a function that works similar to `WNetAddConnection2` function on a UNIX machine?

I only need to be able to validate the username and password against a server. On a Windows platform, I use the WNetAddConection2 method, and I am wondering how to do so on a UNIX platform.

If there is nothing similar, how can I accomplish the validation of username/password against a server?

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve ? WNetAddConnection2 is specific to Microsoft networks. What exactly is the 'resource' (or 'network resource') in your case ?

Comment: I assume the server is a Windows machine.  Is it a domain controller?